# Symfony jms serializer enable when needed

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have jms serializer and in my class entity have annotation. I have case when I need apply jms serializer annotation only in some case. How to do this ? First I think need move annotation from entity class to uml maybe and create some handler where I can enable this annotation for this entity, in the rest of the time jms are not applicable to entity

my entity

```
/**
 * @Annotation\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Application implements ContainsRecordedMessages
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @Annotation\Groups({
 *      "get_application"
 * })
 * @Annotation\Expose()
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @Annotation\Groups({
 *      "post_application"
 * })
 * @Annotation\SerializedName("company_id")
 * @Annotation\Expose()
 */
private $companyId;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Annotation\Groups({
 *      "post_application"
 * })
 * @Annotation\SerializedName("channel_sale")
 * @Annotation\Expose()
 */
private $channelSale;
```

and I have class manager for this entity where I want enable jms and the disable jms serializer annotation

```
class ApplicationManager
{
public function someFunction()
{
    $this->enableJmsForEntity(Application::class);
    //some logic
    //
    $this->disableJmsForEntity(Application::class);     
}
}
```

my goal - that jms serializer don't work in serializer proccess for response. Only in my service, wehre I create entity with `deserializer` function, jms serializer annotation for entity enable. Because in this old project all respons look like this

```
return $this->json($application, Response::HTTP_CREATED);

vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php:114
    protected function json($data, $status = 200, $headers = array(), $context = array())
{
    if ($this->container->has('serializer')) {
        $json = $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($data, 'json', array_merge(array(
            'json_encode_options' => JsonResponse::DEFAULT_ENCODING_OPTIONS,
        ), $context));

        return new JsonResponse($json, $status, $headers, true);
    }

    return new JsonResponse($data, $status, $headers);
}
```

and after adding jms annotation we have problem, response in changing ..

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly your goal is?

Comment: I updated my question